# building query/filter in scala eclipse plugin for elastic search

Tags: scala, playframework, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have this document structure:

```
{
        "_index": "catalogue",
        "_type": "attribute",
        "_id": "f26f19bb-5558-4e01-a021-d81cd895248d",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "id": "f26f19bb-5558-4e01-a021-d81cd895248d",
           "tenantIds": [
              "1",
              "2"
           ]
        }
     }
```

I am making a query that returns all the document that contain certain tenant.

I looks like (In Sense plugin):

```
POST /catalogue/attribute/_search
{
"filter": {"terms": {
   "tenantIds": [
      "1"
   ]
}}
}
```

The problem is when i try to implement in elastic search scala plugin - for eclipse, i get issues and cannot create the query and filter, and i cant find a descent guide.

What i try and get no response is:

```
    val tenantIdFilter = FilterBuilders.termFilter("tenantIds",tenantId.get+",all")
    val totalQuery = IndexQuery[AttributeSearchItem]().withBuilder(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery(),tenantIdFilter))
    val newProducts = this.search(totalQuery)
```

I get empty results. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the `scala eclipse plugin for elastic search`

Comment: https://github.com/cleverage/play2-elasticsearch

Comment: So the elasticsearch plugin for play. Nothing to do with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a Filtered Query with only a `filter`, you have to use a `matchAll` for the `query` part of this `filteredQuery`. In your example, you use an empty `boolQuery` and that's why it returns no result.

You should try something like this :

```
val totalQuery = IndexQuery[AttributeSearchItem]().withBuilder(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),tenantIdFilter))
```

Comment: Hi, I did:         val totalQuery = IndexQuery[AttributeSearchItem]().withBuilder(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("tenantIds", tenantId.get+",all"))// .withBuilder(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery(),tenantIdFilter))
        val newProducts = this.search(totalQuery)